# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}(z-1-i)^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}(z-1-i)^n}$$
but when I tried the ratio test, I got $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\dfrac{\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\dfrac{-1}{n+1}\right|=0$$
so does this mean that the radius of convergence is (sorry for wrong notation; you get it) $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$? This was given as an exercise but we haven't had any examples like this... Is this okay?

Comment: Yes, just like the radius of convergence for $e^z=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$ is infinite. By the way, this is the same example, do you see why?

Comment: I think so... it just got shifted/ centered about $1+i$ and the $-1$ doesn't matter because of the absolute value (?) Okay thank you very much!!

Comment: @Did, You should transform your hint into an answer, which, to my taste should be the most appropriate to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use Cauchy-Hadamard formula when reasonably easy?:

$$\frac1R=\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\right|}=\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies R=\infty $$

Comment: Because when the ratio test is even easier...

Comment: ... being understood that $\sqrt[n]{n!} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$ because of Stirling formula.